# Is there any possibility that we can place the the legends manually using mouse

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot in LogLinear scale I wanted to put the legend in the top of the plot horizontally. Can I place this manually, It is extremely difficult to place it through code. this is my customized legend. The full code is too big and takes more than forty minutes to produce the plot. [image: the final plot]. On top of this line inside the plot, I am planning to place the legend

```
p[5] = Graphics[{Thickness[0.008], AbsoluteDashing[{2, 7}], 
   Line[{{Log[0.001], 13.5}, {Log[0.008] , 13.5}}], 
   Text[StyleForm["Mode 1,", FontSize -> 30], {Log[0.08], 13.5}]}
```

Comment: does something like `DynamicModule[{pt = Scaled[{.5, 1}]}, 
 Plot[x Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, ImageMargins -> 10, 
  ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red], 
  Epilog -> 
   Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], 
     Panel[LineLegend[{Directive[Dashed, Red]}, {"legend"}]], 
     Background -> White, LocatorRegion -> Full]]]]` work?

Comment: `DynamicModule[{pt = Scaled[{.5, 1}]}, 
     Plot[{x Sin[x], x  Cos[x], x Tan[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
      ImageMargins -> 10, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
      PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Red], Directive[Dashed, Blue], 
        Directive[Dashed, Black]}, 
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], 
         Panel[LineLegend[{Directive[Dashed, Red]}, {"legend"}]], 
         Background -> White, LocatorRegion -> Full]]]]`

Comment: How to add legend if there are multiple lines in the plot like above

Comment: acoustics, posted an answer for the example in your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[moveablelegend ]
moveablelegend = DynamicModule[{pt = Scaled[{.5, 1}]}, Show[#, Epilog -> 
  Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], #2, Background -> White, LocatorRegion -> Full]], ##3]] &;
```

**Example:**

```
plt = Plot[{x Sin[x], x Cos[x], x Tan[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  ImageMargins -> 10, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Red], Directive[Dashed, Blue], Directive[Dashed, Black]},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", LabelStyle -> 18,  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}],
  ImageSize -> Large];
```

[image]

```
{plot, legend} = {plt[[1]], plt[[2, 1, 1]]};
moveablelegend[plot, legend, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
moveablelegend[plot, Framed[Rotate[legend, Pi/2], FrameMargins -> 0], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of expression can we say like function 1, function 2, function 3, because I did not  get how to input theses, instead of expression

Comment: @acoustics, you can replace `"Expressions"` with `{"function 1", "function 2", "function 3"}` , that is use `LineLegend[{"function 1", "function 2", "function 3"}, LabelStyle -> 18, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}]`.